# TinyMCE Unable to get property 'setContent' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I know this topic has been covered many times here but no matter which approach I take I either get a error such as "Unable to get property 'setContent' of undefined or null reference" or the line executes but nothing happens.

Here's what I know.
tinymce initializes and is a valid object.
The html variable has the propper HTML which it get from a parent window.
jQuery is loaded and functional.

In addition to the code below I have also tried.

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(html);
tinymce.editors[0].setContent(html);
$('textarea#XRMeditor').val(html);  * Before initialization
```

I have tried all methods before and after tinymce intializes (just in case).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

          <script src="sage_jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
          <script src="tinymce_/tinymce.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
      var html = window.parent.document.getElementById("descriptionIFrame").contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
      debugger;
      //$('textarea#XRMeditor').val(html);
      tinymce.init({
          selector: 'textarea#XRMeditor'
});
      tinymce.get('XRMeditor').setContent(html);

  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <textarea id="XRMeditor">Easy (and free!) You should check out our premium features.</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this issue is that you are trying to talk to TinyMCE before its initialized on the page.

Your `get()` call is in the head of your page and I would doubt that when the browser processes your script that TinyMCE has initialized.  You can use an "init" handler to delay when this call happens:

```
tinyMCE.init({
  //your regular init parameters here...
  setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on('init', function() {
      //load your content here!
      tinymce.activeEditor.setContent(html);
      //or
      tinymce.editors[0].setContent(html);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: alternatively, use `this.setContent(html)`, as `this` is the editor instance